# How parse Perl 6 code using STD.pm6 grammar?

Tags: parsing, raku

I would like minimal working example of parsing Perl 6 code from Perl 6 using STD.pm6
Running something like this

```
use v6;
use STD.pm6;
my $j = slurp 'e:\src\perl6\valid-p6-script.p6';
my $o = STD::Grammar.parse($j);
say $o.perl;
```

under debugger give me absolutely weird output:

```
e:\src\prg\perl6>c:\rakudo\bin\perl6-debug-m.bat -I. p6.p6
>>> LOADING p6.p6
>>> LOADING E:\src\prg\perl6\STD.pm6
Unhandled exception: ctxlexpad needs an MVMContext
   at gen/moar/m-CORE.setting:15136  (C:\rakudo/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm::24)
 from gen/moar/m-CORE.setting:15250  (C:\rakudo/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:AT-KEY:95)
 from gen/moar/m-CORE.setting:4291  (C:\rakudo/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:postcircumfix:<{ }>:4294967295)
 from C:\rakudo/share/perl6/lib/Debugger/UI/CommandLine.pm:736  (C:\rakudo\share\perl6\lib\Debugger\UI\CommandLine.pm.mo
arvm::82)
 from gen/moar/m-CORE.setting:2826  (C:\rakudo/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:sink-all:168)
 from gen/moar/m-CORE.setting:10187  (C:\rakudo/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:sink:36)
 from C:\rakudo/share/perl6/lib/Debugger/UI/CommandLine.pm:730  (C:\rakudo\share\perl6\lib\Debugger\UI\CommandLine.pm.mo
arvm:unhandled:114)
 from C:\rakudo/share/perl6/lib/Debugger/UI/CommandLine.pm:721  (C:\rakudo\share\perl6\lib\Debugger\UI\CommandLine.pm.mo
arvm::25)
 from gen/moar/m-Metamodel.nqp:3586  (C:\rakudo\share\nqp\lib/Perl6/Metamodel.moarvm:enter:28)
 from gen/moar/m-CORE.setting:5190  (C:\rakudo/share/perl6/runtime/CORE.setting.moarvm:CALL-ME:57)
 from gen/moar/m-BOOTSTRAP.nqp:2749  (C:\rakudo/share/nqp/lib/Perl6/BOOTSTRAP.moarvm::93)
 from gen\moar\stage2\NQPHLL.nqp:1425  (C:\rakudo\share\nqp\lib/NQPHLL.moarvm:command_eval:380)
 from src/Perl6/Compiler.nqp:59  (C:\rakudo\share\nqp\lib/Perl6/Compiler.moarvm:command_eval:93)
 from gen\moar\stage2\NQPHLL.nqp:1365  (C:\rakudo\share\nqp\lib/NQPHLL.moarvm:command_line:114)
 from gen/moar/m-perl6-debug.nqp:497  (C:\rakudo\share\perl6\runtime\perl6-debug.moarvm:MAIN:190)
 from gen/moar/m-perl6-debug.nqp:440  (C:\rakudo\share\perl6\runtime\perl6-debug.moarvm:<mainline>:68)
 from <unknown>:1  (C:\rakudo\share\perl6\runtime\perl6-debug.moarvm:<main>:8)
 from <unknown>:1  (C:\rakudo\share\perl6\runtime\perl6-debug.moarvm:<entry>:9)
```

or without debugger:

```
e:\src\prg\perl6>c:\rakudo\bin\perl6.bat -I. p6.p6
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling E:\src\prg\perl6\STD.pm6
Semicolon form of 'grammar' without 'unit' is illegal.  You probably want to use 'unit grammar'
at E:\src\prg\perl6\STD.pm6:8
------> :ver<6.0.0.alpha>:auth<http://perl.org>;<HERE><EOL>
  from p6.p6:2
```

Comment: first, your use statment should just read `use STD` (though it appears to be 'working' anyway); second, `STD` is no longer maintained, and I'm not sure it ever ran on Rakudo anyway - instead, it gets translated to perl5 via `viv`

Comment: note that if you want to use Rakudo to parse Perl6, you can do so via the compiler object returned by `nqp::getcomp("perl6")`; however, as far as I'm aware, that's undocumented...

Comment: how rakudo compile perl 6 and where it's grammar... and so STD.pm6 what for? until now, I thought that the STD.pm6 is a real part of rakudo compiler...

Comment: STD.pm6 was the reference grammar/verifier maintained by Larry during the development of the various compilers (Rakudo, Pugs, Niecza, ...); the torch of reference implementation has essentially passed on to Rakudo, which uses [its own grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp) to parse Perl6

Answer (score 5):

`STD.pm6` was the reference grammar/verifier maintained by Larry during the development of the various Perl 6 compilers (Rakudo, Pugs, Niecza, ...). It comes with a dedicated tool called `viv` that translates it to Perl 5. As far as I know, it never ran on any of the mainstream compilers.

With the 6.c language release, the torch of reference implementation has essentially passed on to Rakudo, which uses [its own grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp) written in NQP to parse Perl 6.

While this Grammar (in combination with the [corresponding actions](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp)) can be used for manual parsing by importing these modules `:from<NQP>`, the more friendly approach (eg no need to declare `$*LINEPOSCACHE`) would be via the corresponding compiler object:

```
say nqp::getcomp('perl6').eval($source, :target<parse>).dump;
```

Other targets of interest might be `:target<syntaxcheck>` as well as the more low-level `:target<ast>` or for the curious perhaps even `:target<mast>`.

Answer (score 2):

Working example from #perl6 conversation:

```
use nqp; 
use Perl6::Grammar:from<NQP>; 
use Perl6::Actions:from<NQP>; 
my $source = q|say "hello world";|; 
my $*LINEPOSCACHE; 
my $p6c = Perl6::Grammar.parse($source, :actions(Perl6::Actions.new())); 
say $p6c.dump
```

Comment: you can get the same result via `nqp::getcomp('perl6').eval($source, :target<parse>).dump`